# How do I mount NFS through nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, nfs

I have an NFS share that I need to connect to (for reasons of speed).

If I try to connect through Nautilus->Connect to Server, I get the error "This file server type is not recognised."

[image: Nautilus Connect to Server NFS attempt showing "This file server type is not recognised."]

I have looked for a Nautilus plugin and only found [nfs-lan](http://nfs-lan.sevka.info/), which appears not to have been touched [since 2013](https://github.com/sevka/nfs-lan), and which also appears to fail a number of package checks.

[image: nfs-lan package fails package checks due to bad quality]
Now, these look minor issues, but it's not a good sign.

**Is there any better option for mounting NFS shares through Nautilus?**

Comment: Apparently GVFS does support NFS now: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gvfs-list/2015-March/msg00000.html, but Ubuntu doesn't have it for some reason: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gvfsd-nfs. Maybe a file a bug report asking for its inclusion.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the tip!   I tried uncommenting the "#nfs: nfs" line in /etc/gnome-vfs-2.0/modules/default-modules.conf but then I realised that the gvfsd-backends package is missing gvfsd-nfs also.  So I think I need to get the package source and compile it back in.

Comment: I got gvfsd-nfs to compile, but it's still not recognising nfs as a file server type. :-(  Looking at the dialog code I suspect unintentional hardcoding! :-\

Answer (score 9):

** **Interim Answer** **

I'm still trying to get the dialog to work properly but, as a temporary workaround, I thought I should share this:

Tested in 15.10, 16.04, and 16.10, if you create a mount point for each NFS mount in `/media/[username]` like this:

```
sudo mkdir /media/user/Kn-Qmultimedia
sudo mkdir /media/user/Kn-Public
```

And then add the intended NFS mounts to `/etc/fstab`   (`sudo gedit /etc/fstab`) like this:

```
192.168.1.100:/Qmultimedia  /media/user/Kn-Qmultimedia  nfs user,noauto 0   0
192.168.1.100:/Public   /media/user/Kn-Public   nfs user,noauto 0   0
```

Then Nautilus will show an NFS mount in the bookmarks that is cleanly mountable and unmountable:

[image: Nautilus showing NFS mounts from fstab]

***Not quite the answer, but it doesn't hurt as much and you can use it until I find the proper answer.*** :-)

Comment: you are now using `mount` instead of `gvfs-mount`.

Comment: @ukos Yep, that's why the answer starts with "**Interim Answer**"  Do you know how to do it with `gvfs-mount`?

Comment: Sorry no. 
I think gio mount is the way to go but I havent trief yet. 

https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/class-giomount.html

Comment: You can add the option`x-gvfs-show` to your `fstab` nfs mounts to add this button to newer nautilus: